# How is tf data handled by velodyne_driver?

Tags: navigation, simulation, odometry, velodyne-driver, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am going to use a Velodyne VPL16 along with the velodyne_driver to publish a PoinCloud2 message to ROS.

I have seen that the velodyne_node has the velodyne's frame_id as a parameter and I wanted to know if this is used just to include the frame_id in the header or if any transformation is being performed while the packages are being read from the raw data provided by the actual Velodyne.

Let me explain: if the Velodyne turns at 10Hz, it means that it takes 0.1s to perform a full revolution. If the Velodyne moves at just 20 Km/h (~5.6m/s), by the time it finishes the revolution it will have moved about 0.56m since it started.

So, if points are passed to ROS via the velodyne_points topic after having completed a 360º sweep, what odometry information should I use? The sensor's position at the beginning of the revolution, at the end, in the middle?

That's why I asked if any transformation was being performed by the velodyne_driver to compensate its own displacement.

I think it just reads the relative coordinates and publishes them converted to PointCloud2, but isn't the movement of the Velodyne introducing a big error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239849/how-is-tf-data-handled-by-velodyne_driver?/) by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2016-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is a problem, if you wait for a full revolution and transform the whole cloud at once.

That is why the [transform nodelet and node](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud#TransformNodelet) exist. It transforms each packet to the `odom` frame, using the robot's pose at the time that packet was acquired.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-07-19**:
I am afraid I did not understand the purpose of the transform nodelet.

So, it will be listening to the /odom frame while velodyne_node is gathering all points and when a full revolution is completed, the transform nodelet will use those transforms to correct the robot's displacement. Is that right?

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-07-20**:
I have just realised that the velodyne_driver has the option to publish a number of packets per message, I thought it would always send a full revolution. Is this how you suggested transform each single package? I think this would publish each packet into ROS, and I intend to publish 360º at once.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-07-21**:
Each packet has its own time stamp, and the `velodyne -> odom` transform is applied as of that moment.

**Comment by [OMC](https://answers.ros.org/users/27334/omc/) on 2016-07-21**:
Oh, I see! I have just discovered the transform listeners. When I tried to understand the code two days ago I thought the transform was done using just the latest tf and that didn't make sense. Now I imagine the transformpointcloud pcl reads the tf buffer and transforms into /odom.

Thanks a lot.